# Performance/memory consumption for saving infos in DB or prefs

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I need to store a lot and variable number of checkboxes status of my Android application.
Every 5-10 mins I need to retrieve the status of a single checkbox (that should be changed by user interaction in other activity).
 I know i can store them on sharedPreferences or in a SQLite db. The number or checkboxes is variable from 10 to *(infinite-1)*.

My first idea was to store all statuses in one single string:

```
chk1:true,chk2:false,chk3:false,chk4:false,chk5:true
```

delimited by `:` and `,`. I can retrieve in one single `getString()` call, all my checkboxes stasus.

I left this solution because my checkboxes are growing in number and I think it's not performing to have a single string with thousand of data.

My second idea was to store every chk in separate preferences. I left this solution because cause I need to retrieve may times my checkboxes status.. imagine  `getString()` called 10000 or more times it's a waste of resource.

My third idea is to store all single status in a SQLite db.

```
 ID   Status
  1      T
  2      F
  3      F
  4      F
  5      T
```

In this solution I don't like that I need to access my DB lots  of time.

What's the best solution (performance and memory consumption) if I need to retrieve a checkbox status every 5 mins from now to infinite? **DB or sharedpref**?
If DB, I need to open every time the db and instantiate a Cursor, or should I instantiate it at the beginning of my activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely go with SQLite.

Both shared preferences and SQLite have cache mechanisms, but SQLite was specifically designed for retrieval and storage of large amounts of data whereas shared preferences are more suited for just simple application... well... preferences.

Moreover SQLite is particularly useful if your data model ever changes (and believe me, this happens all the time). SQLite will also cache just some most used fragments of your data (technically: pages of the database) - it will adapt to the actual usage pattern of your data.

As for opening the DB - I'd definitely recommend opening it once and reuse your created connection multiple times - that will save you from the overhead of opening the database each time (which is a costly operation) and also allow SQLite to learn (adapt) how to cache your data based on how you actually use it (e.g. order of access, particular SQL statement cache, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. Are there any negative point to open a DB connection and never close it (never ~ 2-3 days)?

Comment: most important thing is to always gracefully close all the cursors. the rest is less important, but I simply suggest closing the connection `onDestroy()` of your `Activity` just to be on the safe side. having said that, I doubt that Android will keep your activity that long in memory (because it will destroy it automatically when memory is needed) unless your activity stays in foreground all the time in which case it will really try not to destroy it at all.

Comment: Nope, it's a live wallpaper, so the activity is open and running in 'foreground'. I'll try this solution.

Comment: as far as I know this is not true - if the user goes away from the `Activity` that has wallpaper behind it, it will definitely change its visibility and maybe even destroy it for memory reclaiming purposes. anyway, good luck! :)